# HiveSQL: Query an array of structs

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have a table with an array of structs (originates from Spark parquet file). As an example, The table tree looks like this:

```
| -- family_name : string
| -- kids : array
      | -- element : struct
              | -- name : string
              | -- id : string
              | -- class_grades : struct
                      | -- math : int
                      | -- science : int
```

I'd like to get all the `family_name`s where there's at least one kid with a `math` grade above 90. Note that the number of kids may vary between families. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure it out:

```
SELECT
          family_name,
          grades.math
FROM 
          (SELECT 
                       family_name,
                       grades
           FROM 
                       table_name 
           LATERAL VIEW OUTER 
                       explode(class_grades) c as grades) 
AS 
          exploded_grades
WHERE     grades.math > 90
```